# Extracting attribute value from non context element

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

What I am trying is to get value from attribute.

Here is the input xml:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<office:document-content xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0" xmlns:style="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:style:1.0" xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0" xmlns:table="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:table:1.0" xmlns:draw="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:drawing:1.0" xmlns:fo="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xsl-fo-compatible:1.0" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:meta="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:meta:1.0" xmlns:number="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:datastyle:1.0" xmlns:svg="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:svg-compatible:1.0" xmlns:chart="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:chart:1.0" xmlns:dr3d="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:dr3d:1.0" xmlns:math="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" xmlns:form="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:form:1.0" xmlns:script="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:script:1.0" xmlns:ooo="http://openoffice.org/2004/office" xmlns:ooow="http://openoffice.org/2004/writer" xmlns:oooc="http://openoffice.org/2004/calc" xmlns:dom="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events" xmlns:xforms="http://www.w3.org/2002/xforms" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:rpt="http://openoffice.org/2005/report" xmlns:of="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:of:1.2" xmlns:xhtml="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:grddl="http://www.w3.org/2003/g/data-view#" xmlns:officeooo="http://openoffice.org/2009/office" xmlns:tableooo="http://openoffice.org/2009/table" xmlns:drawooo="http://openoffice.org/2010/draw" xmlns:calcext="urn:org:documentfoundation:names:experimental:calc:xmlns:calcext:1.0" xmlns:loext="urn:org:documentfoundation:names:experimental:office:xmlns:loext:1.0" xmlns:field="urn:openoffice:names:experimental:ooo-ms-interop:xmlns:field:1.0" xmlns:formx="urn:openoffice:names:experimental:ooxml-odf-interop:xmlns:form:1.0" xmlns:css3t="http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-text/" office:version="1.2">
 <office:scripts/>
 <office:font-face-decls>
  <style:font-face style:name="Mangal1" svg:font-family="Mangal"/>
  <style:font-face style:name="Calibri" svg:font-family="Calibri" style:font-family-generic="roman" style:font-pitch="variable"/>
  <style:font-face style:name="Calibri Light" svg:font-family="&apos;Calibri Light&apos;" style:font-family-generic="roman" style:font-pitch="variable"/>
  <style:font-face style:name="Cambria" svg:font-family="Cambria" style:font-family-generic="roman" style:font-pitch="variable"/>
  <style:font-face style:name="DeusEx" svg:font-family="DeusEx" style:font-family-generic="roman" style:font-pitch="variable"/>
  <style:font-face style:name="Liberation Serif" svg:font-family="&apos;Liberation Serif&apos;" style:font-family-generic="roman" style:font-pitch="variable"/>
  <style:font-face style:name="Liberation Sans" svg:font-family="&apos;Liberation Sans&apos;" style:font-family-generic="swiss" style:font-pitch="variable"/>
  <style:font-face style:name="F" svg:font-family="" style:font-family-generic="system" style:font-pitch="variable"/>
  <style:font-face style:name="Arial" svg:font-family="Arial" style:font-family-generic="system" style:font-pitch="variable"/>
  <style:font-face style:name="Mangal" svg:font-family="Mangal" style:font-family-generic="system" style:font-pitch="variable"/>
  <style:font-face style:name="Microsoft YaHei" svg:font-family="&apos;Microsoft YaHei&apos;" style:font-family-generic="system" style:font-pitch="variable"/>
  <style:font-face style:name="SimSun" svg:font-family="SimSun" style:font-family-generic="system" style:font-pitch="variable"/>
  <style:font-face style:name="Times New Roman" svg:font-family="&apos;Times New Roman&apos;" style:font-family-generic="system" style:font-pitch="variable"/>
 </office:font-face-decls>
 <office:automatic-styles>
  <style:style style:name="P1" style:family="paragraph" style:parent-style-name="Standard">
   <style:text-properties fo:font-size="5pt" fo:language="bg" fo:country="BG" officeooo:paragraph-rsid="00118747" style:font-size-asian="5pt" style:font-size-complex="5pt" style:language-complex="ar" style:country-complex="SA"/>
  </style:style>
  <style:style style:name="P2" style:family="paragraph" style:parent-style-name="Standard">
   <style:paragraph-properties fo:text-align="center" style:justify-single-word="false" style:writing-mode="lr-tb"/>
   <style:text-properties officeooo:paragraph-rsid="00118747"/>
  </style:style>
  <style:style style:name="P3" style:family="paragraph" style:parent-style-name="Standard">
   <style:paragraph-properties fo:text-align="center" style:justify-single-word="false" style:writing-mode="lr-tb"/>
   <style:text-properties fo:color="#000000" style:font-name="Cambria" fo:language="bg" fo:country="BG" officeooo:paragraph-rsid="00118747" style:font-name-complex="Arial"/>
  </style:style>
  <style:style style:name="P4" style:family="paragraph" style:parent-style-name="Standard">
   <style:paragraph-properties fo:text-align="center" style:justify-single-word="false" style:writing-mode="lr-tb"/>
   <style:text-properties fo:color="#000000" style:font-name="Cambria" officeooo:paragraph-rsid="00118747" style:font-name-complex="Arial"/>
  </style:style>
  <style:style style:name="P5" style:family="paragraph" style:parent-style-name="Standard">
   <style:paragraph-properties fo:text-align="start" style:justify-single-word="false" style:writing-mode="lr-tb"/>
   <style:text-properties officeooo:paragraph-rsid="00118747"/>
  </style:style>
  <style:style style:name="P6" style:family="paragraph" style:parent-style-name="Style2">
   <style:paragraph-properties fo:margin-top="0cm" fo:margin-bottom="0cm" style:contextual-spacing="false"/>
   <style:text-properties fo:language="bg" fo:country="BG" officeooo:paragraph-rsid="00118747"/>
  </style:style>
  <style:style style:name="T1" style:family="text">
   <style:text-properties fo:font-size="20pt" style:font-size-asian="20pt"/>
  </style:style>
  <style:style style:name="T2" style:family="text">
   <style:text-properties fo:font-size="20pt" fo:language="bg" fo:country="BG" style:font-size-asian="20pt"/>
  </style:style>
  <style:style style:name="T3" style:family="text">
   <style:text-properties fo:color="#b22f2a" style:font-name="Calibri" fo:language="bg" fo:country="BG"/>
  </style:style>
  <style:style style:name="T4" style:family="text">
   <style:text-properties fo:color="#000000" style:font-name="Cambria" fo:language="bg" fo:country="BG" style:font-name-complex="Arial"/>
  </style:style>
  <style:style style:name="T5" style:family="text">
   <style:text-properties fo:color="#000000" style:font-name="Cambria" fo:language="en" fo:country="US" style:font-name-complex="Arial"/>
  </style:style>
  <style:style style:name="T6" style:family="text">
   <style:text-properties fo:color="#000000" style:font-name="Cambria" style:font-name-complex="Arial"/>
  </style:style>
 </office:automatic-styles>
 <office:body>
  <office:text>
   <text:sequence-decls>
    <text:sequence-decl text:display-outline-level="0" text:name="Illustration"/>
    <text:sequence-decl text:display-outline-level="0" text:name="Table"/>
    <text:sequence-decl text:display-outline-level="0" text:name="Text"/>
    <text:sequence-decl text:display-outline-level="0" text:name="Drawing"/>
   </text:sequence-decls>
   <text:p text:style-name="P6">
    <text:span text:style-name="T1"/>
   </text:p>
   <text:p text:style-name="Title">
    <text:span text:style-name="T4">Запознаване със</text:span>
    <text:span text:style-name="T5">JTAG</text:span>
    <text:span text:style-name="T4">протокол за програмиране на</text:span>
    <text:span text:style-name="T5">MSP430</text:span>
    <text:span text:style-name="T4">Запознаване с функционалността на</text:span>
    <text:span text:style-name="T5">Real Time Clock.</text:span>
   </text:p>
   <text:p text:style-name="P5">
    <text:span text:style-name="T5"/>
   </text:p>
   <text:p text:style-name="Subtitle">
    <text:span text:style-name="T4">Създаване на</text:span>
    <text:span text:style-name="Bold_20_Style">
     <text:span text:style-name="T4">часовник</text:span>
    </text:span>
    <text:span text:style-name="T4">с календар в реално време.</text:span>
   </text:p>
   <text:p text:style-name="P5">
    <text:span text:style-name="T4"/>
   </text:p>
   <text:h text:style-name="Heading_20_1" text:outline-level="1">
    <text:span text:style-name="T4">Запознаване с</text:span>
    <text:span text:style-name="T5">UART</text:span>
    <text:span text:style-name="T4">периферията на</text:span>
    <text:span text:style-name="T5">MSP430F5438.</text:span>
   </text:h>
   <text:p text:style-name="P5">
    <text:span text:style-name="T5"/>
   </text:p>
   <text:h text:style-name="Heading_20_2" text:outline-level="2">
    <text:span text:style-name="T4">Създаване на график за аларма и реализиране на прекъсвания по зададени час и дата.</text:span>
   </text:h>
  </office:text>
 </office:body>
</office:document-content>
```

And this is the stylesheet:

```html
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fo="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xsl-fo-compatible:1.0" xmlns:style="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:style:1.0" xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0" xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0" version="1.0">
 <xsl:output method="xml"/>
 <!-- -->
 <xsl:template name="return-lang">
  <xsl:param name="style-name"/>
  <xsl:value-of select="/office:document-content//style:style[@style:name='$style-name']/style:text-properties/@fo:language"/>
 </xsl:template>
 <!-- -->
 <xsl:template name="extract-title">
  <xsl:for-each select="office:body/office:text/text:p[@text:style-name='Title']">
   <para style-name="Title">
    <!--Title is a constant sinse it is a precondition-->
    <xsl:for-each select="text:span">
     <xsl:variable name="language">
      <xsl:call-template name="return-lang">
       <xsl:with-param name="style-name" select="string(@text:style-name)"/>
      </xsl:call-template>
     </xsl:variable>
     <span xml:lan="{$language}">
      <xsl:value-of select="."/>
     </span>
    </xsl:for-each>
   </para>
  </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
 <!-- -->
 <xsl:template match="/office:document-content">
  <text>
   <xsl:call-template name="extract-title"/>
  </text>
 </xsl:template>
 <!-- -->
 <xsl:template match="text:sequence-decls">
  <ofis>
   <xsl:call-template name="extract-title"/>
  </ofis>
 </xsl:template>
 <!-- <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>                      /office:document-content//style:style[@style:name='{$style-name}']/@style:family-->
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This is what I get:

```html
<text xmlns:fo="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:xsl-fo-compatible:1.0" xmlns:style="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:style:1.0" xmlns:text="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:text:1.0" xmlns:office="urn:oasis:names:tc:opendocument:xmlns:office:1.0">
    <para style-name="Title">
        <span xml:lan="">Запознаване със</span>
        <span xml:lan="">JTAG</span>
        <span xml:lan="">протокол за програмиране на</span>
        <span xml:lan="">MSP430</span>
        <span xml:lan="">Запознаване с функционалността на</span>
        <span xml:lan="">Real Time Clock.</span>
    </para>
</text>
```

And this is what I expect:

```html
<text>
    <para style-name="Title">
        <span xml:lang="bg">Запознаване със</span>
        <span xml:lang="en">JTAG</span>
        <span xml:lang="bg">протокол за програмиране на</span>
        <span xml:lang="en">MSP430</span>
        <span xml:lang="bg">Запознаване с функционалността на</span>
        <span xml:lang="en">Real Time Clock.</span>
    </para>
</text>
```

In my opinion there must be some issue in expanding `style-name` parameter.
When I substitute `[@style:name='$style-name']` with `[@style:name='T4']` I get the value of the corresponding `fo:language` attribute. Please excuse my bad English.
Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `@style:name='$style-name'` to `@style:name=$style-name`.